# How can I create a per-application override for DXVK?

Tags: wine, opengl, games

DXVK is an implementation of DirectX on Vulkan (the successor to OpenGL). According to [this comment](https://github.com/doitsujin/dxvk/issues/1824#issuecomment-731188013), you can specify per-application DLL overrides for DXVK in Wine. How can I have one install (a video game) which has two executables `LaunchFoo.exe` and `Game.exe` where only one of those executables uses DXVK?

> Just use wined3d for the launcher with per-application DLL overrides.

How can I do that. Specifically for my work load, I would like `LaucnhFoo.exe` to **NOT** use DXVK (since it doesn't work). I would like *everything* else to use DXVK. If necessary, I can write the executables that I wish to use DXVK explicitly. That is to say, I can whitelist what I want to run under DXVK, but I prefer to blacklist what I do not want to run under DXVK.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me, and I have seen lutris do something similar for other things.

Add this in /user.reg

```
[Software\\Wine\\AppDefaults\\LaucnhFoo.exe\\DllOverrides] 1656252956
#time=1d88967403ff600
"*d3d10core"="d"
"*d3d11"="d"
"*d3d9"="d"
"*d3dcompiler_43"="d"
"*d3dx9_24"="d"
"*d3dx9_25"="d"
"*d3dx9_26"="d"
"*d3dx9_27"="d"
"*d3dx9_28"="d"
"*d3dx9_29"="d"
"*d3dx9_30"="d"
"*d3dx9_31"="d"
"*d3dx9_32"="d"
"*d3dx9_33"="d"
"*d3dx9_34"="d"
"*d3dx9_35"="d"
"*d3dx9_36"="d"
"*d3dx9_37"="d"
"*d3dx9_38"="d"
"*d3dx9_39"="d"
"*d3dx9_40"="d"
"*d3dx9_41"="d"
"*d3dx9_42"="d"
"*d3dx9_43"="d"
```

I have basically just copied the contents under section `[Software\\Wine\\DllOverrides]` (in the same file after installing dxvk with winetricks) and changed `native` to `d`